# Regex capture decimal within a string

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

So I've got a string consisting of a mixture of text, special characters and decimals:

```
2018-12-18 00:00:00 : TEXT0        TEXT1 0,123 - TEXT2 1,123 - TEXT3 2,123 - TEXT4 3,123
```

I'm interested in something that can capture `2,123`. So far I've tried something like:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) : (V04\.10\w+|\w+ ) \w+ \d+,\d{3} - \w+ \d+,d{3} - \w+ (\d+,d{3}) - \w+ \d+,d{3}
```

But it does not seem to work. I'm capturing two more groups here, one for the date in the front and one for `TEXT0` as well. They work fine by themselves. Any hints?

I'm sitting in .NET 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just had few typos in your regex where you wrote only `d` instead of `\d` for intending to capture number and at one place, there were multiple spaces but you just wrote single space due to which it didn't match.

Change your regex from this,

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) : (V04\.10\w+|\w+ ) \w+ \d+,\d{3} - \w+ \d+,d{3} - \w+ (\d+,d{3}) - \w+ \d+,d{3}
```

to this,

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) : (V04\.10\w+|\w+) +\w+ \d+,\d{3} - \w+ \d+,\d{3} - \w+ (\d+,\d{3}) - \w+ \d+,\d{3}
```

And it will start matching and capturing the data as you expect.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/evuueO/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Besides writing `d` instead of `\d` and matching a single whitespace,  you might shorten your regex a bit by repeating the part that matches `\w+ \d,\d{3} -` and make the digit part with the comma a capturing group.

That way the capturing group will be the last occurence of the repeated pattern:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) : (V04\.10\w+|\w+ +)(?:\w+ (\d,\d{3}) - )*\w+ \d+,\d{3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WaSa1H/1)